# GTK 3 C++ icon with label in a button

Tags: c++, gtk3

I am trying to get an icon to appear along side with the label in a button but seems like there is an overriding going on and the button is accepting only **one element** either **label** or **icon**.

here is what i have done so far :

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv);

    Gtk::Window* win = new Gtk::Window;

    Gtk::Image* icon = new Gtk::Image;
    icon->set("src/ui/icons/about.png");


    Gtk::Button* btn = new Gtk::Button;

    btn->set_label("Hello world");
    btn->set_image(*icon);

    win->add(*btn);
    win->show_all();

    return app->run(*win);
}
```

How can i get **both icon and label** to show in the button ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

There is a global-wide Gtk setting, [gtk-button-images](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSettings.html#GtkSettings--gtk-button-images), that distributions or users can use to style applications look. When the value is false, Gtk hides the images in buttons that also have a label.

You can make your button always show the image, regardless of this system setting, by calling [gtk_button_set_always_show_image](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkButton.html#gtk-button-set-always-show-image)

Here's the updated sample:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv);

    Gtk::Window* win = new Gtk::Window;

    Gtk::Image* icon = new Gtk::Image;
    icon->set("src/ui/icons/about.png");


    Gtk::Button* btn = new Gtk::Button;

    btn->set_label("Hello world");
    btn->set_image(*Gtk::manage(icon));
    btn->set_always_show_image(true);

    win->add(*Gtk::manage(btn));
    win->show_all();

    return app->run(*win);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! this works perfect ! i also found annother way `btn->add_pixlabel("src/ui/icons/about.png", "Login",  Gtk::ALIGN_START,  Gtk::ALIGN_CENTER);`